# React Route render blank page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

[image]

Here is the code screenshot.

I want to render **Homepage** component but I want to wrap it into these **MainLayout** component.

The problem is that screen is blank and there is no error in Terminal but when I inspect the page it says "Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element", so guys I know this is version update syntax problem because I had same problem when I was writing `component= {component }` but syntax has been changed and I should have written `element={<component />}`.

So I believe this is also syntax problem but I've done research but couldn't solve. I believe I should change this

```
/* ... */ render = {() => (
  <MainLayout>
    <Homepage />
  </MainLayout>
)}
```

somewhat into newer syntax but don't know how.

Comment: can you pls edit the question and show your code ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Route` components in `react-router-dom` v6 no longer take `component` or `render` props; the routed components are rendered on the `element` prop ***as JSX***.

```
<Routes>
  ...
  <Route
    path="/"
    element={(
      <MainLayout>
        <Homepage />
      </MainLayout>
    )}
  />
  ...
</Routes>
```